# C# Parsing key phrases with synonyms

Tags: c#, parsing, time, nlp

I am working on a string parser that will read a phrase or sentence and parse it for schedule/timing information. For example, the input might include the phrase

> "TWO TIMES PER DAY"

or

> "ON MONDAY, WEDNESDAY, AND FRIDAY"

The goal is to create a template that can be converted into a list of `DateTimes` when given a start and end date. I have thought about storing this template as a `Func<DateTime, bool>`:

The former example could be possibly be interpreted as `(d => d.TimeOfDay == TimeSpan.FromHours(8) || d.TimeOFDay == TimeSpan.FromHours(18))` or whatever times make the most sense.

The latter example could be interpreted as `(d => d.TimeOfDay == TimeSpan.FromHours(8) && (d.DayOfWeek == Monday || d.DayOfWeek == Wednesday || d.DayOfWeek == Friday))`.

I could then loop through each hour between the start and end dates and add the time to the schedule if the function returns true.

What I am having trouble with is the parsing. My current solution is to create a dictionary with all the phrases that I might expect, and the appropriate filters as values. However, this is beginning to look very messy and unsustainable, especially with the amount of overlap possible:

```
var phrases = new Dictionary<string, Func<DateTime, bool>>()
{
    { "DAILY", (d => true) },
    { "A DAY", (d => true) },
    { "PER DAY", (d => true) },
    { "EVERY DAY", (d => true) },
    { "SUNDAY", (d => d.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday) },
    { "SUN", (d => d.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday) },
    { "MONDAY", (d => d.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday) },
    { "MON", (d => d.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday) },
    . . .
}
```

What is a better way to do this?

Comment: Might want to look into Natural Language Processing.

Comment: it'd probably be helpful to write/implement a DFA (deterministic finite automata).  you start in a "start state" then go through each word in the sentence and make a transition to a new state (or back to the current one) based on how that word affects what "kind" of sentence it is.  you will have to come up with the rules for these transitions though.

Comment: Check this out: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38553/TaskScheduler

Comment: What are the different phrase templates that you want to support? Because the more freedom you leave to the user (or the input provider) the more tedious your task will be.

Comment: The existing data that I'm using for reference comes in a lot of different formats, but there is an expectation that any particularly unusual data will be left for the user to enter manually. The intent is just to reduce the amount of work the user has to perform.

Answer (score 0):

To handle this completely is a very hard problem.  I handle many (but not all) possibilities in my Natural Language Engine for .NET (https://nuget.org/packages/AboditNLP/).

One of the challenges is that English is ambiguous: 'MONDAY' could mean this Monday, next Monday or last Monday depending on the context.

Your basic approach is a good one: combining functions that map a date time onto the desired value.  But the output of the function may need to be a single date time or a date time range, or a collection of date time ranges (e.g. every Monday in May 2013).  There are also many phrases people use that are in effect an infinite range, and you may need to enumerate these to get the next one (or several) (e.g. every Monday).

English DateTime expressions can express either a query or a generative sequence.  What you want for a query against a database (a SQL or LINQ Expression) may be very different from what you want when putting the expression into a calendar entry.

The built-in Datetime and TimeSpan classes in .NET are inadequate to represent most english language date time expressions you will encounter.  They have no way to represent common intervals like "two weeks", and cannot handle ranges, collections, intersection, union and all the other combinations you will need.

From a parsing perspective you cannot simply go from left to right. Like arithmetic, temporal operators may have precedence rules.  For example, "the last Friday in May" really needs to be handled as `InfiniteRepeatEveryYear(LastOf(IntersectionOf(all Fridays, all Mays)))`, i.e. "Friday in May" needs to be parsed before you can apply "the last" to it.

It's a very hard problem, good luck!

Comment: Fortunately, the scope of my project is much more limited than that! The expected output is always a series of calendar entries for events with very limited durations (instantaneous for my purposes).